# JKalman Variable Understanding

Tags: java, android, statistics, sensors, kalman-filter

I just downloaded a java library called JKalman (link: https://sourceforge.net/projects/jkalman/), but I am having some trouble undrestanding the terminology. I don't have the time to dive in and learn the nuances of Kalman Filters at the moment, I would simply like to utilize the library to reduce noise from a sensor I am using - an accelerometer. I understand that noise from accelerometers is great, which is why I will be utilizing my sensor alognside others, beside the point but this is just extra backing for the program - not what I rely on entirely.

I would like to know how to properly initialize and apply the class to get a 'corrected' matrice.

I don't know the necessary information, but I will try my best to supply it if you ask for it. I will give some prelimary info here:

Sensor varies from -2 to 2 units (g forces)

The biggest issue I am having is understanding the constructor for the class which demands measurement parameters and dynamic paramaters. If someone could take a look and give me a run down of what to input to get the corrected data, that would be enough.

Comment: "I don't have the time to dive in and learn the nuances of Kalman Filters at the moment".  You should absolutely **not** use a Kalman Filter in that case.  It is not the sort of algorithm you apply by grabbing a library and calling some functions.